Revision and help on counting how many ternary strings are there given certain constraints
A ternary string is a sequence of digits, where each digit is 0, 1, or 2. How many ternary strings of length 55 are there such that the string contains exactly twenty-one 1s, the string corresponding to the first twelve positions has exactly six 1s and two 2s, and the string corresponding to the last thirty-three positions contains the substring 2101021?
This is how I've approached the problem.
Since in the first 12 positions we have exactly 6 ones and 2 two:
$\binom{12}{6} * \binom{6}{2}$
We have 55-12-33 = 10 middle positions. Since we have no constraint here it would mean $3^{10}$? Not sure.
Lastly I to account for the substring in the last 33 positions and multiplicate that for the remaining available positions and remaining available ones.
For string 2101021:
$\binom{27}{1}*\binom{36}{12}$
For string
2101021
     2101021

: $\binom{22}{1}*\binom{31}{10}$
For string 2101021 2101021: $\binom{21}{2}*\binom{29}{9}$
For string
2101021
     2101021
          2101021

: $\binom{17}{1}*\binom{26}{8}$
For string
2101021
     2101021 2101021

: $\binom{16}{2}*\binom{24}{7}$
For string
2101021 2101021
             2101021

: $\binom{16}{2}*\binom{24}{7}$
For string 2101021 2101021 2101021:
: $\binom{15}{3}*\binom{22}{6}$
I am afraid this approach is incorrect I would like revision and help on this kind of problem.

For each of these it's probably best to first consider simpler cases where possible. For instance, suppose you want to count all permutations of 012122. If it were 012345, there's 6! permutations. But if 3 can't be distinguished from 1 and 4,5 can't be distinguished from 2, then that brings the number down be a factor of 2!*3!.

I tried and failed to find any approach where the math was not extremely ugly.  The constraint that at least one occurrence of 2101021 occurs in the last 33 positions makes this extremely ugly.  I considered each of the direct approach, inclusion-exclusion, stars and bars, and recursion.  No joy.  This exhausts the tools that I know about.
